# Determine if storyboard is active if myStoryboard havent begun yet?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, animation, storyboard

1- Copy and paste following code into **MainWindow.xaml** file.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel>
    <Label x:Name="Label1" Height="25" Width="100" Background="Gainsboro"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" Height="25" Width="100" Background="Pink" Text="Hello"/>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

2- Copy and paste following code into **code behind** file.

```
Class MainWindow

Private WithEvents myDispatcherTimer As New System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer

Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    AddHandler myDispatcherTimer.Tick, AddressOf myCode_Tick
    myDispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5)
    myDispatcherTimer.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub myCode_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim myColorAnimation As New Animation.ColorAnimation With {.From = Colors.Transparent, .To = Colors.Red, .Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.4), .AutoReverse = True}
    Animation.Storyboard.SetTargetName(element:=myColorAnimation, name:="Label1")
    Animation.Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(element:=myColorAnimation, path:=New PropertyPath("(Label.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"))
    Dim myStoryboard As New Animation.Storyboard
    myStoryboard.Children.Add(myColorAnimation)

    If Not TextBox1.Text = "Hello" Then
        myStoryboard.Begin(containingObject:=Me, isControllable:=True, handoffBehavior:=Animation.HandoffBehavior.SnapshotAndReplace)
    Else
        If myStoryboard.GetCurrentState(containingObject:=Me) = Animation.ClockState.Active Then
            myStoryboard.Stop(containingObject:=Me)
        End If
    End If

End Sub

End Class
```

3- Run this project, wait two seconds and see this error: https://prnt.sc/n08a3j

Error message:

> Cannot perform action because the specified Storyboard was not applied
>   to this object for interactive control

So, how can I solve that error?

***How to determine if storyboard is active if myStoryboard havent begun yet?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's 2 problems here, the first one is that your code does not call the `Begin` method unless the text is changed. The `Begin` method however determines if the `Storyboard` is **controllable**.

In order to call `GetCurrentState` it needs that **controllable** flag.

So make sure you call `Begin` first (I don't know what your application is supposed to do upon the initial text but did you mean to use the **NOT** operator in `If NOT TextBox1.Text = "Hello" Then`?

Second, you want to pass in the **containingObject** to the `GetCurrentState`:

`If myStoryboard.GetCurrentState(containingObject:=Me) = Animation.ClockState.Active Then`

I've applied the 2 changes and the app is able to run the animation without an exception.